# Python test - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'status_code'

Tags: python, unit-testing, error-handling, mocking, pytest

Writing some unit tests in python, have simplified this to some functions to focus on the issue

So 2 functions are this

```
def function_to_throw_http_error():
    logger.info("function_to_throw_http_error")


def function_to_catch_http_error():
    try:
        function_to_throw_http_error()
    except HTTPError as http_err:
        logger.error(f"HTTP error occurred external service: {http_err}")
        return {"statusCode": http_err.response.status_code, "body": http_err.response.reason}
```

Test is this

```
    @patch(
        "functions.my_file.function_to_throw_http_error", Mock(side_effect=HTTPError(Mock(status_code=404), 'error')),
    )
    def test_catching_http_error_reposnse(self):
        response = function_to_catch_http_error()
        self.assertTrue('error' in str(response))
```

but when i run the test I am getting the following error

```
>           return {"statusCode": http_err.response.status_code, "body": http_err.response.reason}
E           AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'status_code'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#the builtins module itself has no HTTPError as default class
import builtins
print(dir(builtins))
#just printing out the exception classes from buitins directory

''''['ArithmeticError', 'AssertionError', 'AttributeError', 'BaseException', 'BlockingIOError', 'BrokenPipeError', 'BufferError', 'BytesWarning', 'ChildProcessError', 'ConnectionAbortedError', 'ConnectionError', 'ConnectionRefusedError', 'ConnectionResetError', 'DeprecationWarning', 'EOFError', 'Ellipsis', 'EnvironmentError', 'Exception', 'False', 'FileExistsError', 'FileNotFoundError', 'FloatingPointError', 'FutureWarning', 'GeneratorExit', 'IOError', 'ImportError', 'ImportWarning', 'IndentationError', 'IndexError', 'InterruptedError', 'IsADirectoryError', 'KeyError', 'KeyboardInterrupt', 'LookupError', 'MemoryError', 'ModuleNotFoundError', 'NameError', 'None', 'NotADirectoryError', 'NotImplemented', 'NotImplementedError', 'OSError', 'OverflowError', 'PendingDeprecationWarning', 'PermissionError', 'ProcessLookupError', 'RecursionError', 'ReferenceError', 'ResourceWarning', 'RuntimeError', 'RuntimeWarning', 'StopAsyncIteration', 'StopIteration', 'SyntaxError', 'SyntaxWarning', 'SystemError', 'SystemExit', 'TabError', 'TimeoutError', 'True', 'TypeError', 'UnboundLocalError', 'UnicodeDecodeError', 'UnicodeEncodeError', 'UnicodeError', 'UnicodeTranslateError', 'UnicodeWarning', 'UserWarning', 'ValueError', 'Warning', 'ZeroDivisionError']'''

# so in order to use HTTPError use the requests module

import requests
try:
    #your required code
    pass
except requests.HTTPError as exception:
    #print your exception using print(exception)
    pass
```

Comment: Sorry not really following, I am importing from requests import HTTPError

Comment: plus I am catching the error in my code so I wouldn't be able to test that way would I?

Comment: In that case your error might be occuring here because the HTTPError doesn't have a response attribute.
print(HTTPError.response.status_code)
Traceback (most recent call last)
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'HTTPError' has no attribute 'response'

Comment: Yea think thats it but how do I add it?

Comment: I tried with your code above but got same error   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'status_code' which makes me think httperror might be null

Comment: you can just try printing exception ( print(exception)) inside the except block..   also httperror doesn't have response and you've made a small typo the code in 'status_code' is with a 's' it's status_codes..  also httperror doesn't have the status_codes . you can use status codes by calling it via requests module..  requests.status_codes..

Comment: This is the way it comes back from the external service so I can't change the function, will have to change the tests to suit. When I print the exception it prints None, not sure why

Comment: In that case you'll have to refer elsewhere.It would be easy for me had i known about the "external service". Anyways thanks for interacting so well. This is my first answer on stackoverflow.. it would be nice if you upvoted it (novice's expectations..:))..

Comment: Well I do think the http_err.response.status_code would be code and not codes, because it only has 1 code. So I not blaming the external service, I think i need to figure out how to set the response and status code on the mock object

Comment: If you can write a test for the function above come back and you will have a question answered :)

Comment: i shall definitely try.. :). thanks for the upvote btw.. means a lot